# How to detect if any elements currently have mouseenter active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically, I have an un-ordered list with around 12 list items. I would like to apply a style to them when the mouse is over any of them, and a different style when the mouse is over none of them.

For example, the following is my current code that only has a style when `li`'s are being hovered.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'},100,'easeOutBack');
});
$('li').bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.7'},600,'easeOutBack');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbgn8/)**

I would like to style all the `li` to have `opacity:1` when no `li` is being hovered over.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Bind a separate callback to the `mouseleave` event of the `ul`.

Comment: sorry not clear on what you are looking for

Comment: @tewathia, Like so? - `$('ul').bind('mouseenter',function(){ DO STYLING HERE });`

Comment: when the page is loaded you want opacity to be .7 or 1 then if an item is hovered then you want that element to have opacity 1 and others .7 then when mouse leaves you want opacity to be 1 again

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Spot on

Comment: @fizzix like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kC7dU/3/ ?

Comment: @fizzix Yeah, it would work. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/ZNHS3/ (I've just added red/green colors, you can put whatever style/opacity you want)

Comment: @fizzix if you can give the following answers.. 1) what is the opacity you want on page load? 2) When a `li` is hovered what should be its opacity and what should be the opacity of other `li`s? 3) when the mouse leaves the hovered `li` what is the opacity for all `li`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with CSS only, if I understand correctly, you want to have all items at full opacity when none is hovered, and have full opacity on the one that's hovered and less opacity on the rest. Here's an example with just CSS:

```
li {
  opacity: 1;    
}

li:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul:hover li {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sbgn8/2/

Comment: I think this is most probably the best solution, and by far the fastest. I will need to structure my code to fit this in, but it is work it. Also, never knew that `ease-in-out` was accessible in CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, always use CSS for animations if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class for the ul element that will cause all lis to be 100% opaque. Then, upon hovering a li, remove that class from the ul (its parent).

I'll give you a code if I sounded confusing.

Note that I've added a CSS transition, I suggest you do all of them using CSS (that way you won't have to deal with inline rules overriding all others).

```
$('li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'},100);
    $(this).parent().removeClass('full');
});
$('li').bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.7'},600, function(){
        $(this).css('opacity', '')
    });
    $(this).parent().addClass('full');
});
```

Here's what I had on my mind: http://jsfiddle.net/fqVT8/1/

Comment: Little buggy upon leave of the `ul`

Comment: @fizzix I believe it's because it wait for the JS anims to finish, then runs the CSS transition. Very obvious when you quickly move the mouse. That's why I suggested a fully-CSS solution, if possible.

Comment: Removed the ul padding, seems ok now (Chrome/Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$('li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
     $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'},100,'easeOutBack');
});
$('li').bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.7'},600,'easeOutBack');
});
$("ul").bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $("li").animate({'opacity': '0.7'},200,'easeOutBack');
})
$("ul").bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $("li").animate({'opacity': '1'},200,'easeOutBack');
})
```

Comment: Missed adding jquery and jquery ui ;). Well, if you change animations time to 1 milisecond it works fairly well

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the selector inside the handler function? Changing this...

```
$(this).animate({'opacity': '1'},100,'easeOutBack');
```

to this....

```
$('li').animate({'opacity': '1'},100,'easeOutBack');
```